# equivalent of Contains for Decimal types

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, decimal, contains, equivalent

I was wondering if there is an equivalent property for `Contains` in a `Decimal` type in vb.net.

What I would want is:

```
Dim dec as decimal
Dim input as string
dec.Contains(input)
```

This is for a filtering function purpose, but it says, `Contains` is not a member of `Decimal`.

Comment: why not just convert the decimal to the string? Why is it a decimal if you're searching within it like this?

Comment: Because in the actual project, I have a table, so it is: Dim table as Table and then I have table.decimal_attribute.Contains(input). The table attribute needs to be a decimal, and I am filtering from a control outside of a radgrid

Comment: pull out the value, convert to string, search

Comment: Solved it! I added 'Imports System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' then  I did StringConvert(table.decimal_attribute, 6).Contains(input)